# How do votes affect reputation near the daily limit?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

If I receive upvotes after hitting the daily limit, and then a single downvote, does that put me back below the limit again? Or is the reputation cap calculated on a per-day basis?

Answer (score 3):

> If I receive upvotes after hitting the daily limit, and then a single downvote, does that put me back below the limit again?

Yes.

> Or is the reputation cap calculated on a per-day basis?

No. More like an event stream.